# Express Mongo callback returning undefined when query returns object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express

I am working on a Node/Express project that has a MongoDB, but I am having a problem passing the result of the Mongo query callback to the route in my app.js file.

Within my MongoDB set-up files, I have the following method which accesses two collections and returns an array of riders:

```
RiderClass.prototype.findByCarpoolDriver = function(driverID, callback) {
    this.getCollection(function(error, rider_collection) {  //returns db.riders
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        carpoolClass.findRidesForDriver(driverID, function(err, carpools){
          var rider_ids = [];
          for(var ii=0;ii<carpools.length;ii++){
            rider_ids.push(new ObjectID(carpools[ii].rider_id));
          }

          rider_collection.find( {_id:{$in : rider_ids}}).toArray(function(e, riders){
            console.log(riders);  //prints out fine
            callback(riders);

          });
       });

      }

    });
};
```

The problem comes in my `app.js` file, when I call a route:

```
var RiderClass = require('./rider_class').RiderClass;
var riderClass = new RiderClass('localhost', 27017);

app.get('/driver/:id/rides', function(req, res) {
    riderClass.findByCarpoolDriver(req.params.id, function(error, riders) {
        console.log(riders);   //undefined
        res.send(riders);
    });
});
```

The `console.log(riders)` in my Mongo File prints the array as I'd expect it, but the `console.log(riders)` in my `app.js` file returns an undefined.  And I don't think it is an async problem because the mongo log is printed before the undefined app.js one.

The only thing I can think is that maybe it a problem with querying multiple collections?  But even then I can see from logging it that the array passed to the `callback()` is good so why isn't it defined in the `app.js`?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `riderClass.findByCarpoolDriver`, the callback function you're passing in takes two parameters:

```
function(error, riders) {
    console.log(riders);   //undefined
    res.send(riders);
}
```

but in both places where you call `callback`, you're only passing in one parameter. Since you don't use the error parameter, you probably want to change that callback function to just:

```
function(riders) {
    console.log(riders);   //undefined
    res.send(riders);
}
```

But then you will want to delete/change this line:

```
if( error ) callback(error)
```

since the callback was never using the `error` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
// one argument passed to callback...
callback(riders);

// ...but two arguments expected:
riderClass.findByCarpoolDriver(req.params.id, function(error, riders) {
  ...
});
```

So call the callback with two arguments as well:

```
callback(null, riders);
```